# Adding string in existing url using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am using VBScript for programming

I have three vairables and there value is coming through vbscript program.

```
publicationPath = "/test/english"

publicationUrl = "/101/english"

publishedPath = "/test/english/about/india/delhi.aspx"
```

Now if you see the **publicationPath** and **publishedPath's** "/test/english" is same. Now I want that this will be replaced with the publicationUrl value, I mean the final url will be as given below.

```
pagePublishPath = /101/english/about/india/delhi.aspx"
```

Please suggest the solution using VBScript

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace a substring with another substring within a string, use the [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954.aspx) function:

```
pagePublishPath = Replace(publishedPath, publicationPath, publicationUrl, 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: Unless you are including a lot of built-in constants, you will need to add vbtextcompare =  1, or just substitute 1 in the line.

Comment: @Remou: `vbTextCompare` is an intrinsic constant in VBScript, and there's no need to define it (at least in WSH scripts).